# NGINX not using fast_cgi downloads php as a file

Tags: php, nginx

I have a NGINX site config that serves a file from a wildcard subdirectory, and passes the URI to the query string of the index.php file in that directory.

I have set up debugging and it seems like it's able to find the correct directory and index.php file, but never serves the index.php file with the query string attached. It just downloads my PHP file.

Here is my NGINX config file:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www;

    server_name <my ip address>; 

index index.php index.html index.htm;
autoindex on;

location /dev {
        autoindex on;
    }

location ~ ^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*) {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /dev/$portal/index.php?_url=$uri;
}

    location /assets {
       # try_files $uri $uri/;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /opn {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /opn/index.php?_url=/$uri;
        autoindex on;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

client_body_buffer_size     90M;
client_max_body_size        100M;

}
```

I get the following from my debug log:

```
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: post event 00000000025DC630
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: delete posted event 00000000025DC630
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: posix_memalign: 00000000025A7980:256 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 accept: 172.56.39.58 fd:10
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: posix_memalign: 00000000025C8B90:256 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 event timer add: 10: 60000:1479851471914
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 reusable connection: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 epoll add event: fd:10 op:1 ev:80002001
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: post event 00000000025DC630
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: delete posted event 00000000025DC630
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: posix_memalign: 00000000025C8CA0:256 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *2 accept: 172.56.39.58 fd:12
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: posix_memalign: 00000000025C8DB0:256 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *2 event timer add: 12: 60000:1479851471920
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *2 reusable connection: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *2 epoll add event: fd:12 op:1 ev:80002001
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http wait request handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 malloc: 00000000025C8EC0:1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 recv: fd:10 423 of 1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 reusable connection: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 posix_memalign: 00000000025C2950:4096 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http process request line
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http request line: "GET /dev/portal HTTP/1.1"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http uri: "/dev/portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http args: ""
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http exten: ""
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 posix_memalign: 00000000025B5250:4096 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http process request header line
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Cookie: PHPSESSID=jpi52v69f09p9f0aaqhtkvcgm3"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header done
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 event timer del: 10: 1479851471914
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 test location: "/dev"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*)"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http regex set $portal to "portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http regex set $therest to ""
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 using configuration "^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*)"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:104857600
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 8
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 9
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 10
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 11
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post access phase: 12
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 try files phase: 13
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http script var: "/dev/portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 trying to use file: "/dev/portal" "/var/www/dev/portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http script var: "/dev/portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 trying to use dir: "/dev/portal" "/var/www/dev/portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 try file uri: "/dev/portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 14
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 15
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 17
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 18
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 19
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http filename: "/var/www/dev/portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 add cleanup: 00000000025C3798
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http static fd: -1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http dir
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http finalize request: 301, "/dev/portal?" a:1, c:1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http special response: 301, "/dev/portal?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http set discard body
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 xslt filter header
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 21:50:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: http://104.196.238.47/dev/portal/
Connection: keep-alive

2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 00000000025C3848, pos 00000000025C3848, size: 207 file: 0, size: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:207
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http output filter "/dev/portal?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http copy filter: "/dev/portal?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 image filter
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 xslt filter body
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http postpone filter "/dev/portal?" 00000000025C3940
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 00000000025C3848, pos 00000000025C3848, size: 207 file: 0, size: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000006DDAC0, size: 132 file: 0, size: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00000000006DDDA0, size: 52 file: 0, size: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:391
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter limit 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 writev: 391
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/dev/portal?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/dev/portal?" a:1, c:1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 set http keepalive handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http close request
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http log handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025C2950, unused: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025B5250, unused: 2566
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025C8EC0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 tcp_nodelay
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 reusable connection: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 event timer add: 10: 65000:1479851476920
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http keepalive handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 malloc: 00000000025C8EC0:1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 recv: fd:10 -1 of 1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025C8EC0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: post event 00000000025DC630
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: delete posted event 00000000025DC630
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: accept on 0.0.0.0:80, ready: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: posix_memalign: 00000000025C8EC0:256 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *3 accept: 172.56.39.58 fd:14
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: posix_memalign: 00000000025C8FD0:256 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *3 event timer add: 14: 60000:1479851471921
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *3 reusable connection: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *3 epoll add event: fd:14 op:1 ev:80002001
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http keepalive handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 malloc: 00000000025C90E0:1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 recv: fd:10 424 of 1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 reusable connection: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 posix_memalign: 00000000025C2950:4096 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 event timer del: 10: 1479851476920
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http process request line
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http request line: "GET /dev/portal/ HTTP/1.1"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http uri: "/dev/portal/"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http args: ""
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http exten: ""
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 posix_memalign: 00000000025B5250:4096 @16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http process request header line
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header: "Cookie: PHPSESSID=jpi52v69f09p9f0aaqhtkvcgm3"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http header done
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 test location: "/dev"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*)"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http regex set $portal to "portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http regex set $therest to "/"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 using configuration "^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*)"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:104857600
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 8
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 9
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 10
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 11
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post access phase: 12
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 try files phase: 13
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http script var: "/dev/portal/"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 trying to use file: "/dev/portal/" "/var/www/dev/portal/"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http script var: "/dev/portal/"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 trying to use dir: "/dev/portal/" "/var/www/dev/portal/"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 try file uri: "/dev/portal/"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 14
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 15
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 open index "/var/www/dev/portal/index.php"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 internal redirect: "/dev/portal/index.php?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 test location: "/dev"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*)"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http regex set $portal to "portal"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http regex set $therest to "/index.php"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 using configuration "^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*)"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:104857600
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 8
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 9
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 10
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 access phase: 11
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post access phase: 12
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 try files phase: 13
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http script var: "/dev/portal/index.php"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 trying to use file: "/dev/portal/index.php" "/var/www/dev/portal/index.php"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 try file uri: "/dev/portal/index.php"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 14
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 15
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 16
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 17
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 18
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 content phase: 19
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http filename: "/var/www/dev/portal/index.php"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 add cleanup: 00000000025C37F0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http static fd: 15
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http set discard body
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 xslt filter header
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 21:50:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 325
Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 21:43:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "58336a71-145"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 00000000025B56F8, pos 00000000025B56F8, size: 252 file: 0, size: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:252
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http output filter "/dev/portal/index.php?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http copy filter: "/dev/portal/index.php?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 image filter
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 xslt filter body
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http postpone filter "/dev/portal/index.php?" 00007FFF4B2638E0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 00000000025B56F8, pos 00000000025B56F8, size: 252 file: 0, size: 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:1 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000000000, size: 0 file: 0, size: 325
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:577
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter limit 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 no tcp_nodelay
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 tcp_nopush
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 writev: 252
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 sendfile: @0 325
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 sendfile: 325, @0 325:325
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/dev/portal/index.php?"
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/dev/portal/index.php?" a:1, c:2
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http request count:2 blk:0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/dev/portal/index.php?" a:1, c:1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 set http keepalive handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http close request
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http log handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 run cleanup: 00000000025C37F0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 file cleanup: fd:15
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025C2950, unused: 40
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025B5250, unused: 2301
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025C90E0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 reusable connection: 1
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 event timer add: 10: 65000:1479851476992
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 post event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 delete posted event 00000000025DC768
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 http keepalive handler
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 malloc: 00000000025C90E0:1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 recv: fd:10 -1 of 1024
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2016/11/22 21:50:11 [debug] 1849#0: *1 free: 00000000025C90E0
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to understand how `nginx` selects the `location` block to use to process a request.

In your case, the URI `/dev/index.php` is processed by the first regular expression that matches it, which is not what you want.

Reorder your regular expression `location` blocks like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
location ~ ^/dev/(?<portal>[^/]+)(?<theRest>.*) { ... }
```